# Grouping an Array and Counting items creating new array based on Groups

Tags: javascript

My knowledge on manipulating arrays is really poor, i was wandering if i could get any help with this. i have an `array("dataResult")` .that has got Region, Fruits and User information. i want to Group this information based on Region and also count the number of unique users for each group.

```
dataResult = [{ region: "Africa", fruit: "Orange", user: "Gary" }, 
              { region: "Africa", fruit: "Apple", user: "Steve" },
              { region: "Europe", fruit: "Orange", user: "John" }, 
              { region: "Europe", fruit: "Apple", user: "bob" }, 
              { region: "Asia", fruit: "Orange", user: "Ian" }, 
              { region: "Asia", fruit: "Apple", user: "Angelo" }, 
              { region: "Africa", fruit: "Orange", user: "Gary" }]`
```

I would like my final array to look like the array below to reflect the grouped result and count of unique users for each group

`NewResult = [{ region: "Africa", count: 2 }, { region: "Europe", count: 2},{ region: "Asia", count: 2}],`

Any ideas on how this can be acheived? i have seen some good info on how to group results but i'm struggling with getting the count for uniques user for each group.

**Code for Grouping**

```
var categoryNames = groupBy(dataResults, '2');
console.log(categoryNames);

function groupBy(items,propertyName)
{
    var result = [];
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
      if ($.inArray(item[propertyName], result)==-1) {
          result.push(item[propertyName]);
      }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: you data arrays are not valid.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at MDN's Array page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array It will help you understand arrays a bit better (and their structure). But you might also want to look at objects: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp as in your case you might want your original 'array' to be an object instead. And if you're feeling like a challenge, something like lodash's _.groupBy(): https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.1#groupBy would be a more advanced path to take (which works with both array & object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With proper data, you could iterate the array of objects and count the regions.

```js
var dataResult = [{ region: "Africa", fruit: "Orange", user: "Gary" }, { region: "Africa", fruit: "Apple", user: "Steve" }, { region: "Europe", fruit: "Orange", user: "John" }, { region: "Europe", fruit: "Apple", user: "bob" }, { region: "Asia", fruit: "Orange", user: "Ian" }, { region: "Asia", fruit: "Apple", user: "Angelo" }, { region: "Africa", fruit: "Orange", user: "Gary" }],
    grouped = [];

dataResult.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.region]) {
        this[a.region] = { region: a.region, count: 0 };
        grouped.push(this[a.region]);
    }
    this[a.region].count++;
}, Object.create(null));
  
console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For unique user, you might use an extended hash table

```js
var dataResult = [{ region: "Africa", fruit: "Orange", user: "Gary" }, { region: "Africa", fruit: "Apple", user: "Steve" }, { region: "Europe", fruit: "Orange", user: "John" }, { region: "Europe", fruit: "Apple", user: "bob" }, { region: "Asia", fruit: "Orange", user: "Ian" }, { region: "Asia", fruit: "Apple", user: "Angelo" }, { region: "Africa", fruit: "Orange", user: "Gary" }],
    grouped = [];

dataResult.forEach(function (a) {
    var key = [a.region, a.user].join('|');
    if (!this[a.region]) {
        this[a.region] = { region: a.region, count: 0 };
        grouped.push(this[a.region]);
    }
    if (!this[key]) {
        this[key] = true;
        this[a.region].count++;
    }
}, Object.create(null));
  
console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Part with a decent look at the hash table and some explanations in the code.

```js
var dataResult = [{ region: "Africa", fruit: "Orange", user: "Gary" }, { region: "Africa", fruit: "Apple", user: "Steve" }, { region: "Europe", fruit: "Orange", user: "John" }, { region: "Europe", fruit: "Apple", user: "bob" }, { region: "Asia", fruit: "Orange", user: "Ian" }, { region: "Asia", fruit: "Apple", user: "Angelo" }, { region: "Africa", fruit: "Orange", user: "Gary" }],
    grouped = [],               // result array
    hash = Object.create(null); // oposite of {}, this object does not contain any prototypes

dataResult.forEach(function (a) {

    // build key with region + name, spot pipe in hash
    var key = [a.region, a.user].join('|');

    // check if region is not in hash table
    if (!this[a.region]) {

        // create new object with region and count and insert it into hash table
        this[a.region] = { region: a.region, count: 0 };

        // push the object to the result
        grouped.push(this[a.region]);
    }

    // check if if not region and user exists, it means
    // the user in the region is not counted yet.
    if (!this[key]) {

        //create hash entry
        this[key] = true;

        // increment count 
        this[a.region].count++;
    }
}, hash);
  
console.log(hash);
console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the code snippet Nina, My apologies for my lazy attempt at  typing the array correctly. i noticed your result shows count 3 for Africa, is there a way of avoiding duplicate names. Since Gary appears 2 i was hoping it will count as 1. how can i modify what you already have to take care of duplicate names

Comment: thanks so much Nina. This worked perfectly for my case.
Just for learning purposes and for people who are new to this. would you be able to explain how the code works. maybe some comments. But really thanks

Comment: @OgbobeBuko, please see last snippet. if you have a question, does not hesitate to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is turn your array into an object because your final array is not a valid array.

So you want to return something that looks like this.

```
 newResults = {Africa: 2, Europe: 2, Asia: 2}
```

You would need to right a function that iterates through the array and returns a new object with the desired key and value pairs. Take a look at the map and reduce functions in Javascript, they may be some help.

Reduce
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Map
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: i realize my error now with invalid array, so i have corrected it now for the benefit of newbies like me thanks for the links too. Yes i am trying to create new object that holds the number of unique users within a region.

Comment: No worries, we've all been there