# How to filter and count items in Typescript from an Array

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I would like to filter and count items in Typescript from an Array.

I tried the code below that give me this result: AA,BB,AA,CC

```
const types = cars.map((car) => car.type);   

const cars = [
        {
            id: 2,
            brand: "Opel",
            type: "AA",
        },
        {
            id: 8,
            brand: "Toyota",
            type: "BB",
        },
        {
            id: 40,
            brand: "Opel",
            type: "AA",
        },
        {
            id: 66,
            brand: "BMW",
            type: "CC",
        }
    ];
```

I would like to count and order by **type** like below, how can I do that in Typescript?

**2AA , 1BB, 1CC**

Comment: Please **search thoroughly** before posting, there have been dozens of questions about how to group items in an array (and thus count them). More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouping an Array and Counting items creating new array based on Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891420/grouping-an-array-and-counting-items-creating-new-array-based-on-groups)

Comment: You might find my TS library [`blinq`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blinq) useful. There's an example of almost exactly this in the README. Look for "*count the number of cars for each manufacturer*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [lodash](https://lodash.com/)

```
var result = _.countBy(cars, 'type');
```

Output:

```
{
'AA': 2
'BB': 1
'CC': 1
}
```